# Django - how to render all pages of pdf files at once

Tags: django, pdf

I am trying to make a pdf viewer in HTML template using pdf.js in Django framework.

I had used a code that I got from a Youtube channel Traversy Media on how to create a custom PDF Viewer With JavaScript. It is working but I want to know if it's possible to render all pages at once.

[Here's the link of the pdf.js full code in GitHub](https://github.com/bradtraversy/pdf_viewer/blob/master/js/main.js)...

Is there an alternative way rather than sticking to this code?

Comment: It's difficult to tell what is being asked here, and this question cannot be reasonably answered in its current form. Please provide the context, and/or post code samples of what you have done (i.e.: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com))

Comment: [pdf.js](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js) by Mozilla provides a lot of options. Try that.